# Meaning of the pstree output

Tags: process, ps

```
-bash-3.2$ pstree 27108
Script.sh---java---15*[{java}]
```

What does this `15*` mean here, also any meanings defined for `[]` & `{}` in the context of command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its right there in the `man` page:

```
   pstree shows running processes as a tree. The tree is rooted at either pid or init
   if pid is omitted. If a user name is specified, all process trees rooted  at  pro-
   cesses owned by that user are shown.

   pstree  visually  merges identical branches by putting them in square brackets and
   prefixing them with the repetition count, e.g.

       init-+-getty
            |-getty
            |-getty
            ‘-getty

   becomes

       init---4*[getty]

   Child threads of a process are found under the parent process and are  shown  with
   the process name in curly braces, e.g.

       icecast2---13*[{icecast2}]
```

In your case, the process 27108 was started by the script `Script.sh`. The `Script.sh` created a `java` process which spawned another 15 java threads.

A `ps -eLf | grep java | wc -l` should returned you a count around the number 15.

Answer (score 2):

`man pstree`:

```
  pstree visually merges identical branches by putting them in square brackets and prefixing them with the repetition count, e.g.

       init-+-getty
            |-getty
            |-getty
            `-getty

   becomes

       init---4*[getty]

   Child threads of a process are found under the parent process and are shown with the process name in curly braces, e.g.

       icecast2---13*[{icecast2}]
```

So, `15` threads of `java` process.